# Importing a pre-uploaded file into a value field for a file upload

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, file-upload, upload

I am finishing off a database entry aspect of a project and have got 1 remaining snag that's interfering.

The database is in MySQL but fully accessible via a web site, this includes posting new entries as well as calling up current entries and editing them before replacing the originals.

So far it works fine for all text based entries and I can create a form, populate it with the old entries automatically, make any corrections and resubmit, thus allowing updates without needing to re-enter everything.

Unfortunately, the final part of it is a selection of pictures. The uploading process works fine I cant find out how to import a value field into the upload box or if it is even possible. Because the nature of the upload code looks for a file I think it needs something there to work and simply importing an address wont work. the field for uploading a file is as shown below...

```
<div id="productpic" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:280px;width:150px;height:16px;z-index:5;text-align:left;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Product Picture (Main Display):</span></div>
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="50000000">
<input type="file" id="photo" style="position:absolute;left:180px;top:280px;width:200px;height:23px;line-height:23px;z-index:7;" name="photo" value="Upload a picture!">
```

Because of this, if I don't upload a new file it removes the old one replacing it with a plank entry. This logic leads me to think that rather then populate a field with old data I need a "if" statement to determine if anything has been submitted but I am unsure how to incorporate it.

The script relating to uploading a file is shown below:

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
  $target = "uploads/";
  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

  //This gets all the other information from the form



  //Writes the photo to the server
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
  {

  //Tells you if its all ok
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
  echo "<br>,<br>";
  }
  else {

  //Gives and error if its not
  echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading photo 1.";
  echo "<br>,<br>";
  }
```

I've commented it as best I can for fast reading.

After a file is uploaded its location is then saved to a MySQL Database using the following code to get the new location and then write it.

```
$productpicture=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$data = "UPDATE `classifieds` SET username='$Nusername', productname='$Nproductname',      productdescription='$Nproductdescription', productpicture='$productpicture', sellerspostcode='$Nsellerspostcode', productprice='$Nproductprice' WHERE id=".'"'.$Key.'"'; 
$query = mysql_query($data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error());
```

I think I need to create a conditional if statement for placing the new picture location in the database, so that if it is blank it wont just delete the entry.

To do this would I create a conditional "if" statement that uploads to the database only if the required picture location fields are filled?

I hope this makes sense, ive been working on this for 12 hours a day the the last 2 weeks - mainly as this is my first time doing any php development.

Thanks!